# Why isn't a class being added to a loaded nav element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
this.loadTemplate = async(currentPage) => {
  let promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    $(() => $("#nav").load("./nav.html"));
    $(() => $("#footer").load("./footer.html"));
    resolve("resolved");
  });

  let result = await promise;
  console.log(result);
  $(`#${currentPage}`).addClass("current-page");
};
```

Above is the code for loading and adding the class to the nav.html file. Which should change an element to orange. 
Which it doesn't.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So for the purposes of your question, all the async code can essentially be omitted, focusing only on adding the `current-page` class to the element with the `id` of the supplied `currentPage`?

Comment: Please show us your HTML...  `$(`#${currentPage}`)` certainly refers to nothing because you don't have an element with that id...

Comment: Why do you mix async and promise and why do you await task just after you made it async?

Comment: `.load()` is asynchronous. You're resolving the promise before either of them completes.

Comment: @Barmar is right, you should use jQuery built-in callback parameter.

Comment: BTW, you're actually adding document ready event handlers in your promise. `$(() => {})` does the same as `$(function () {})`, which is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function() {})`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not let jQuery do the job or not use jQuery

```js
let currentPage = "someId";
$("#nav").load("./nav.html", function() {
  $("#footer").load("./footer.html", function() {
    $("#" + currentPage).addClass("current-page");
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not waiting for the `.load()` functions to complete.

You can use `$.get` to get a promise for each AJAX request. You can use `$.when()` to create a new promise that waits for all of them (it's the jQuery equivalent of `Promise.all()`).

```js
this.loadTemplate = async(currentPage) => {
  let promise = $.when(
    $.get("./nav.html", function(response) {
      $("#nav").html(response)
    }),
    $.get("./footer.html", function(response) {
      $("#footer").html(response)
    })
  );

  let result = await promise;
  console.log(result);
  $(`#${currentPage}`).addClass("current-page");
};
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer was downvoted - second solution from @mplungjan takes longer because one request waits for another and here is parallel solution.